# Roblox ContextAction triggers twice

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried to use Roblox ContextActionService to create a button in Roblox for mobile but whenever I press the GUI button it triggers and when I release the button it triggers too. I want it to only trigger once when I press the button.

```
function tpggle()
    print("L pressed")
end
ContextActionService:BindAction("ToggleLight", tpggle, true, Enum.KeyCode.L)
ContextActionService:SetTitle("ToggleLight","L")
ContextActionService:SetPosition("ToggleLight",UDim2.new(1, -97,1, -133))
```

```
I expected:
  L pressed
I got:
  L pressed(x2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action handler `tqggle` is most likely called twice. Once for pushing the button, once for releasing the button.

Try this:

```
function tpggle(actionName, inputState, inputObj)
  if inputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin then 
    print("L pressed")
  end  
end
```

So it will only print something if you push the button.

Refer to

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/ContextActionService/BindAction

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/InputObject/UserInputState